# How to copy data of cell an past it in another cell with max of caracters and another condition

Tags: vba, excel

Please, I want to copy data of a cells in another cells of the same sheet with conditions:

1. the max of characters to copy should be 20
2. If all characters of a cell is less than 20, I have to copy the characters (for example 8 characters) and 12 empty spaces.

You can find my code here

```
For i = 1 To table1Rows 
    table1(1 + i, 27) = table1(1 + i, 1) & " ; " & table1(1 + i, 2) & " ; " & table1(i + 1, 40) & " ; " & table1(i + 1, 17) & " ; " & Right(table1(i + 1, 4), 20) & " ; " & table1(i + 1, 3) & " ; " & Right(table1(i + 1, 41), 16) & " ; " & Right(table1(i + 1, 42), 12) & " ; " & Right(table1(i + 1, 44), 12) & " ; " & Right(table1(i + 1, 46), 16) & " ; " & table1(i + 1, 47) & " ; " & table1(i + 1, 48) 
Next
```

Comment: Please add code only as text formatted as codeblock (indented with at least 4 spaces) so other people can copy that code to test or fix it. Also include in your question what your code actually does and what you expect it to do and where you got stuck or if there are any error messages and where.

Comment: hi you should place code in code sample, copy paste your code here, highlight your code and press (Ctrl + k)

Comment: I modified it. so you can now copy the code.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For i = 1 To table1Rows
    temp = table1(1 + i, 1) & " ; " & _
           table1(1 + i, 2) & " ; " & _
           table1(i + 1, 40) & " ; " & _
           table1(i + 1, 17) & " ; " & _
           Right(table1(i + 1, 4), 20) & " ; " & _
           table1(i + 1, 3) & " ; " & _
           Right(table1(i + 1, 41), 16) & " ; " & _
           Right(table1(i + 1, 42), 12) & " ; " & _
           Right(table1(i + 1, 44), 12) & " ; " & _
           Right(table1(i + 1, 46), 16) & " ; " & _
           table1(i + 1, 47) & " ; " & _
           table1(i + 1, 48)

    ' table1(1 + i, 27) = Left(temp & Space(20), 20)
    table1(1 + i, 27) = Left(temp & "                    ", 20) 'Edited as per comment
Next
```

Comment: Space should work, but I have added an alternative now

Comment: Thanks, I found another code that works even if it doesnt works for one of my cells